# Plot certain information from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame holding Crime information with total crime values for the past 12 months. When I plot the data frame I get a graph showing lines for every `crimeType`.

Is there anyway I can plot a graph for each specific `crimeType` over the course of the year?

This plots my entire graph.

```
crimeMonthDf.plot().legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))
```

Some `crimeType`'s are `Anti-social behaviour` and `Robbery`.

If more info is needed, ask.

Comment: Sure, share example of your data and desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps select each crime type and plot each as a separate series. i.e

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    for ctype in crimeMonthDf['crimeType'].unique():
        ax.plot(crimeMonthDf.loc[crimeMonthDf['crimeType'] == ctype, label=ctype)
    plt.legend()
```